# AUTHENTICATIONFAILED when using python to check inbox with imap

Tags: python, email, smtp, imap

I'm trying to write client for sending and checking emails. I managed to make it work for gmail, hotmail and yahoo emails. I did this using [imap_tools](https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools) / [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) for checking inbox and [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) for sending emails.
However when i tried using custom domain name (ex: mailhost box with [instructions](https://support.mailhostbox.com/configure-your-desktop-email-clients-to-send-and-receive-email/)) i always get `imaplib.error: b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.'`.
I don't see any more configuration needed.

Code i used:

```
 imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host="host.something.com", port=993) 
 imap.login(user, pwd)
```

and using imap_tools

```
with MailBox(host).login( user, pwd) as mailbox:
flags = (imap_tools.MailMessageFlags.ANSWERED, imap_tools.MailMessageFlags.SEEN)
result = mailbox.fetch()
```

Any help appriceated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check mailbox security settings, for alloy to login by robots

Here is the answer: [I encounter an AUTHENTICATIONFAILED error when connecting to email with imaplib library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963552/)

Comment: Please vote to close as duplicate instead of posting a link to another question as an "answer".